# SQL Oracle incremental counter

Tags: oracle

I got a question for you hoping you will help me.

This is my table:

```
Username   Time     Action
--------   ------   ------
Franck     10.11    LogIn
Mark       10.14    LogIn
Luke       10.17    LogIn
Mark       10.18    LogOut
Mary       10.21    LogIn
```

I would like to have a counter column adding +1 every time it found a Login action, and removing -1 every time a Logout action is present.

Something like this:

```
Username   Time     Action   Counter
--------   ------   ------   -------
Franck     10.11    LogIn      1
Mark       10.14    LogIn      2
Luke       10.17    LogIn      3
Mark       10.18    LogOut     2
Mary       10.21    LogIn      3
```

How can I do this?

I tried to add a countif but it's not the right way to proceed

Comment: you can use the `sum()` function and have a case so that when you `logIn` it increments by 1 and when you `logOut` decrements by 1, and then use the over command so you can perform it on all the rows you have
`SUM(CASE WHEN Action = 'LogIn' THEN 1 WHEN Action = 'LogOut' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY Time) AS Counter`

Comment: It would be good to post your current code to add correction to something than writing the code instead of your attempt. Especially when there's no `countif` in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytic (window) variant of `sum` and apply it between all the previous rows (i.e., `unbounded preceding`) and the current row:

```sql
SELECT   username,
         time,
         action, 
         SUM(CASE action WHEN 'LogIn' THEN 1 WHEN 'LogOut' THEN -1 END) 
             OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS counter
FROM     events
ORDER BY time
```